# Drupal 7 Login can't view admin bar, Fresh Install via Drush on CentOS 6.3

Tags: apache, drupal-7, centos, drush

I've spent quite a few hours trying to figure out what the problem is. The issue is:

Login works but the page doesn't change once I log in as admin. I know that the login works because wrong credentials generate an error. I do not even see the administrative toolbar. No other pages exist on the page, but if I am to, say, input ?q=admin, on user/1, it will go 'Access Denied'

What I've done:

- cleared cache and cookies many times
- have checked that mod_rewrite works
- the cookie path on the drupal settings.php is / and not \
- .htaccess is on the drupal root directory, exactly as provided by
  drupal.org
- in httpd.conf, I have written a new directory and AllowOverride=All
  (*note: the parent directory has AllowOverride=None)
- Clean URL's are enabled via drush vset

What I suspect the problem is, but don't know how to solve it:

- Proxy?
- Some permissions that need to be configured on some files/directories

What I have:

- CentOS 6.3
- Apache 2.2.15
- Drush 5.9
- Drupal 7.22

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to reinstall. It´s too weird and it's a new install, so, whatever is happening, maybe it will go away reinstalling Drupal. I don´t think the it's a file permissions problem because otherwise you can't install. Maybe is a session problem, you can also try to install Joomla to see if it works. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a SELinux problem. I found out that if I logout via the logout URL and then use https on my website, I can login and use it properly. I needed to reinstall the certificates and setup the security... Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine that this would be a permissions issue, but if it were, you could just start by doing (and btw, I would NEVER recommend doing this on a production server):

```
cd /<path_in_which_drupal_root_sits>
chown -R apache:apache <drupal_root>
chmod -R 777 <drupal_root>
```

You might need to sudo to do these, and you will definitely want to bring the chmod permission back down to 775, 755 or 644 as is appropriate to the directory/sub-directory once you're done testing.

This will probably not solve  your issue outright, but it will at least help you to eliminate permissions as an issue.

To test proxy issues, you might try installing lynx (command-line http client), and try accessing your site through it using localhost.  You should be able to login, and if you get a different result that way than via remote access, you might indeed have some weird proxy or other network issue that's interfering.

Lastly, and this might actually be the most helpful bit here, you ought to inspect your headers before, during and after the login process.  You can do this using FireBug or Developer Tools or the like.  And, of course, check your Apache access and error logs for anything unexpected or out of the ordinary.

Most likely, though, you just need to reinstall and try it again.